# Rails - Conventions for Complex & Nested Routes (non-resourceful)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some more complex routes setup in my app, that I'm wondering could be turned into resourceful routes.

What are the ideal Rails conventions for turning these into resourceful routes?

**Route 1: /grandparent-place/parent-place/place/**

These routes are at the bottom of my routes.rb file, as they pull from the root path and are scoped by parents and children.

Routes.rb

```
get ':grandparent_id/:parent_id/:id', to: 'places#show', as: :grandparent_place
get ':parent_id/:id', to: 'places#show', as: :parent_place
get ':id', to: 'places#show', as: :place
```

Places_Controller.rb

```
def set_place
  if params[:parent_id].nil? && params[:grandparent_id].nil?
    @place            = Place.find(params[:id])

  elsif params[:grandparent_id].nil?
    @parent           = Place.find(params[:parent_id])
    @place            = @parent.children.find(params[:id])

  else
    @grandparent      = Place.find(params[:grandparent_id])
    @parent           = @grandparent.children.find(params[:parent_id])
    @place            = @parent.children.find(params[:id])

  end
end
```

Application_Helper.rb

```
def place_path(place)
    '/' + place.ancestors.map{|x| x.id.to_s}.join('/') + '/' + place.id.to_s
end
```

**Route 2: /thread#post-123**

These routes are meant to allow for only specific actions, using the parent module to specify the controller directory - and using a # anchor to scroll to the specified post.

Routes.rb

```
resources :threads, only: [:show] do
  resources :posts, module: :threads, only: [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

Application_Helper.rb

```
def thread_post_path(thread, post)
  thread_path(thread) + '#post-' + post.id.to_s
end
```

Is it convention to override the route paths in the application helper, or is there a better way to generate the correct URLs without overriding the helpers?

Answer (score 0):

Path variables are used to specify resources and usually one variable specify one resource. For example:

```
get '/publishers/:publisher_id/articels/:article_id/comments/:id'
```

In your setup you have `places` as a resource.

So, in this endpoint `get '/places/:id'` :id specifies which place should be retrieved.

Regarding your first route it would be most appropriate to leave just one get endpoint:

```
resource :places, only: [:show] # => get '/places/:id'
```

and pass the id of the parent or grandparent as :id whenever you need to retrieve the parent or grandparent place. That way you won't need any conditions in set_place method and so have:

```
def set_place
  @place = Place.find(params[:id])
end
```

In case you need to access parents or grandparents of a place object you can build:

```
 get '/places/:place_id/parents/:parent_id/grandparents/:id'
```

or just leave `get '/places/:place_id/parents/:id'` and whenever you need to access a grandparent just make the call starting from your parent place instead of the child. Route setups can vary depending on your needs. Rails provides various examples on that matter: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Regarding the helpers, there isn't a general rule for overriding or not your path methods and again it mostly depends on the application's needs. I think it is a good practice to keep them intact as much as possible. In your case instead of overriding the path method you can place:

```
thread_posts_path(thread) + '#post-' + post.id # => /threads/7/posts#post-15
```

directly in your view, for example:

```
link_to 'MyThredPost', thread_posts_path(thread) + '#post-' + post.id
```